# The difference between ASP .NET Core with Angular template and Standalone Typescript Angular Project

Tags: angular, visual-studio, .net-core

In Visual Studio (I'm working with Visual Studio 2022) you can create two kinds of Angular projects.

1. ASP .NET Core with Angular
2. Standalone Typescript Angular Project

What is the difference between these two?

[image: The two kinds of templates]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first uses .net core to provide an API to the Angular app, the second is a straight-up Angular app.

Answer (score 5):

The first one host both the front-end angular app and the back-end ASP.NET Core API, as a single project.

Meanwhile the second (Standalone) is new approach introduced with Visual Studio 2022 that allows to keep the front-end Angular app and the back-end ASP.NET Core API in two separate projects, although fully able to interoperate with each other.

Comment: which one is preferable? Doesn't the second template provide better separation of concern? Does the angular part differ for both templates at all?